# Faster list duplicate 'limiter'

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Given some list, e.g., `{5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4}`, I need to limit the duplicates, if any, to an arbitrarily chosen number. The excess duplicates are to be chopped from the end of the list, order of list must be otherwise untouched. For example, with a limit of 2, the above example would become `{5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 0, 4}`.

List can contain pretty much anything that would make sense. I'm using

```
Module[{o = Ordering@#},
   o[[o]] = Join @@ Range /@ Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]];
   Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 - o], 1]] &[yourListHere, dupeLengthLimitHere]
```

which is fairly quick, wondering if there's a better can-opener for this.

Comment: Your code would be hard to beat.

Comment: I would urge you to post your code as an answer. Normally I wouldn't, because OP's attempts are often subpar and there's lot of room to work on improving them. In this case, your code is pretty fast and uses all the "right" functions (at least, for a pure _Mathematica_ implementation). I would much rather vote for your code and answer, rather than a clone of it that just compiled it or changed a few characters.

Comment: Using `Ordering` here takes at least half of the time. If we really want something that is substantially faster, we will have to make do without `Ordering`. Note that `Ordering` is O(n log n), whereas there should be an O(n) algorithm. "Just compiling" something here then also has limited effect, though I guess it would be a nice exercise, especially to avoid the `Join@@`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Well, that's nice to hear from you, but I'm always expecting some out-of-the-box-thinking answer that changes the game...

Comment: @rm-rf: Thanks for the comment, I may end up doing so (though it always feels 'wrong' to me to approve my own answer). I'm checking replies below and testing another method of mine, so I'll wait a bit more.

Comment: @rm-rf don't you think something can be learned from "just compiling" (please see my other comment)? Also you mention "subpar". I feel it should be possible here to ask questions with good code, asking for even better code. In my opinion, `Compile` then becomes a crucial ingredient. Focussing (too much) on pure Mathematica solutions may contribute to creating an ivory tower.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I think you entirely misunderstood what I wrote. I meant that a lot of questions asked are of the type where OP has working code that uses plenty of inefficient loops, operations that (unknowingly unpack), etc. While that technically is also a solution, it might not be a good answer to the question. My point was that rasher's code is really good and far better than what one might just quickly cookup (and in most other questions) and thus is better posted as an answer that can be voted upon.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I fully agree with you re: the uses of Compile and if someone had actually managed to efficiently and cleverly compile the algorithm, then it would be worthy of an answer. The pure mma vs compile part of my comment was just to clarify that I don't find an answer that just (literally) wraps a compile around the OP's code to be an improvement (if it's that simple, then OP is probably aware of it). I didn't mean to suggest that we should only be programming in pure mma (I would never really suggest that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It appears my original effort is appropriate for a pure MM implementation: some of the suggestions mirrored another method I tried that *sometimes* was *slightly* faster but at the expense of much heavier memory use, and often *much* slower.

For reference, code reposted:

```
Module[{o = Ordering@#},
   o[[o]] = Join @@ Range /@ Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]];
   Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 - o], 1]] &[yourListHere, dupeLengthLimitHere]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the range of the integers in the list is limited, the following is quite a bit faster. It uses much more memory if `kk` is considerably larger than `Length@list`.

```
cfu =
 Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {lim, _Integer}, {kk, _Integer}},

  Block[
   {ar, res, val}
   ,
   ar = ConstantArray[0, kk];
   res = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
   Do[
    val = list[[i]];
    If[
     ar[[val]] < lim
     ,
     Internal`StuffBag[res, val];
     Increment[ar[[val]]]
     ]
    ,
    {i, Length@list}
    ];
   Internal`BagPart[res, All]
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

**Generating input**

Warning, do not choose `kk` too high. If you choose `kk = 1*^9` for example, you will probably crash your kernel. Even though such a value of `kk` would lead to sensible input, the compiled function has no safeguard against this.

```
kk = 2*^6;
nn = 1*^6;
rands = RandomInteger[{1, kk}, nn]; ;
```

**Timing comparison**

```
(myRes = cfu[rands, 2, kk]) // Timing // First
```

> 0.067658

```
(resOP = Module[{o = Ordering@#}, 
       o[[o]] = Join @@ Range /@ Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]];
       Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 - o], 1]] &[rands, 2]) // Timing // First
```

> 1.091691

```
myRes === resOP
```

> True

**Notes**

Maybe we can use a hashtable if the only restriction on the input is that they are machine integers/elements of an integer packed array/64 bit integers in my case.

Comment: Just so you know I'm not "against" `Compile`, this is almost exactly what I came up with yesterday (array indexed increments + bags), but didn't post it because I was still trying to find a way to avoid picking a `kk` and do it all in 1 scan of the list (and then fell asleep while thinking about it). Perhaps I should've posted it :)

Comment: @rm-rf thank you for clarifying :). I envy you for being able to fall asleep thinking about MMA :P. Feel free to edit my answer with any ideas you have cooked up while awake or otherwise :)

Comment: Neat, but already have a solution based on code L.S. posted that is similar speed, but as said in OP, list can contain pretty much anything. As an aside, for some reason using the `@` in comment has stopped working for me - any ideas?

Comment: @rasher ah yeah maybe they changed the rules about using @. It seems you can now only @ people who were already active in the comments (not sure). Anyway perhaps I should work out the idea with hashtables. But if the list can really be a mixture of strings integers symbols and what have you it becomes really uninteresting to compile.

Answer (score 2):

A second go, this time a derivative of the rasher's original.

```
    f[list : {__Integer}, limit_Integer] := 
    Transpose[
      SortBy[
        Apply[Join, Map[If[Length[#] > limit, #[[1 ;; limit]], #] &, 
                        GatherBy[Transpose[{Range[Length[list]], list}], 
      Last]]], 
    First]][[2]];
```

On this instance with a limit of 2...

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {10000000}];
```

My timings give 1.61 seconds for the original and 0.936 seconds for this.

Comment: I had tried a similar method (I'll update OP later with it), and found it sometimes was *slightly* better, but often fell apart, e.g., with 100K length of 100K possible distinct elements, my similar method is 4-5X slower. In addition, the gather/sort become memory hogs with large lists, as in 10X memory needs of my current method. I might just write a C stub to do this for really huge lists, but I'd prefer to stay in pure MM. Thanks for the comments & updates.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Ymareth, but coming out slightly faster for me:

```
f[x_, lim_] := x[[Sort @ Flatten[
     #[[;; Min[lim, Length[#]]]] & /@
      GatherBy[Range @ Length @ x, x[[#]] &]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a small internal dictionary to keep track of the duplicate count.

```
f[list : {__Integer}, limit_Integer] := 
Module[{d}, 
  Reap[Scan[(If[!NumberQ[d[#]], d[#] = 1]; 
       If[d[#] <= limit, (d[#] = d[#] + 1; Sow[#])]) &, list]][[2, 1]]]
```

Comment: But unfortunately it is not faster.

Comment: @Kuba: Seems to give incorrect results. Is there a typo? e.g., with `{1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5}` limited to 2, it should be `{1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5}` but I'm getting `{1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5}` from your code.

Comment: @rasher Indeed, except that is not my code :P

Comment: Not so much a typo as not checking my code! Apologies. Re: speed, I think that would depend on distribution of input, number of unique values vs number of duplicates.

Comment: But no, it looks like the OP wins :(

Answer (score 1):

Darn close to the original time-wise. I kind of prefer this for readability..

```
 Function[{list}, 
      list[[Sort@
        Flatten[Position[list, #, 1, dupeLengthLimitHere] & /@ 
        DeleteDuplicates@list ]]]]@yourListHere
```

Comment: Try it with sparse duplicates, e.g., with `RandomInteger[50000,100000]` it is orders of magnitude slower.