# Mathematica 9 can't compile Increment Part with C

Tags: compile

Why can't *Mathematica* 9 compile this code?

```
x = {1};
Compile[{}, x[[1]]++;,
    {{x[[1]]++, _Integer}, {x[[1]], _Integer}}, CompilationTarget :> "C"][]
```

After printed message `CompiledFunction::cflist`, the value of `x` is (in my case) `` {2 + Compile`Variable$29510} ``.

Searching this site for "Compile Increment" found [Faster list duplicate 'limiter'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40765/faster-list-duplicate-limiter/40842#40842), where an `Increment` is used in `Compile` and run correctly. I tried to fix my code using `Block`:

```
Compile[{}, Block[{x}, x = {1}; x[[1]]++; x[[1]] ], CompilationTarget :> "C"][]
```

Those also work.

```
x = {1}; Compile[{}, x[[1]] += 1;, CompilationTarget :> "C"][]
```

(replace `++` by `+=1`) or

```
x = {1}; Compile[{}, x[[1]]++;][]
```

(remove `CompilationTarget -> "C"` part)

This seems like a bug. Is that fixed in *Mathematica* 10?

Comment: All of these implementations that modify a global `x` call `MainEvaluate`. You can use [`CompilePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/ref/CompilePrint.html) to check that.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. At first I thought it was exacerbated by your unusual external patterns (should be `{{x, _Integer, 1}}`, IMO). But actually changing that does not make a difference. There must be an error in the `CCodeGenerator\`` package.

Comment: Just a note that this problem persists at least until version 11.0.1.